# How do I declare the objects having array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to write a declaration for following output as all the values will be get by the user,

```
{
  "name":"ABC",
  "city":"X", 
  "child": [{"name":"ccc","age":"22"}, {"name":"ccc","age":"22"} ]
}
```

where there is the main object **parent** having name and city attributes and an **array of child objects** having name and age attributes.

In short, I want the syntax (or declaration statements for parent and array of child objects respectively).

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: declaration statements for both parent object and array having child objects in javascript

Comment: I'm confused - why does the code here work?

Comment: @VLAZ code here is not working.. I want this type of ouput that's why I am asking for help regarding the structure.

Comment: Then why doesn't it work? It's doing exactly what you describe - you have a main object with `name` and `city` and an array of child objects with `name` and `age`. I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is the way to declare a nested array, where the properties of the higher level array represent a parent object, and has other properties inside which represent child objects.

That's how you would do it if you wanted to work with arrays.

If you're looking for a constructor, or a single-line invocation, you might want to look up ES6 classes: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/es6-classes/